# Android espresso tests clash with ActivityScenario causing "main thread" error (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso, androidx, android-testing

I have the following sample code:

```
@get:Rule
    val activityRule = ActivityScenarioRule<KeyActivity>(intent)


    @Test
    fun test()
    {
        activityRule.scenario.onActivity {
           onView(withText("some text")).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
        }
       
    }
```

and it produces the following error:

```
Method cannot be called on the main application thread (on: main)
```

I have tried running the code in coroutines such as:

```
runTest {
  launch{
    //code
   }
}
```

As well as using `launch<Activity>(intents)`, and using `@UIThreadTest`.

From what I've found anything running inside of `onActivity{}` is put onto the main thread, and the espresso tests that go inside `onActivity` cannot be run on the main thread. So I'm not too sure how to get around testing my activity.